# How to create a Job Log in a Spark Streaming Context?

Tags: apache-spark, performance-testing, spark-streaming

I am currently performing a performance test on my Spark Streaming application. 
In general terms, I am receiving JSON messages via a socket connection, one message per second.
I then process the messages as RDDs with Spark Streaming methods, and finally print the resulting RDDs to a database.

Here's my problem: whenever I want to check the Block Processing Times, or the Schedulling Delays, etc, I need to go to the Spark UI on port 4040.

What I want to do though, is to create a Log with these values, as the program runs, and store it as a txt file in a certain directory.

Now I know that, with a SparkContext, I can use the addSparkListener method for example, or Logger.

How can I do this for a Spark Streaming Context?

Thank you so much, apologies if I was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is querying [Sparks REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) which exposes these metrics via JSON formatted HTTP requests:

> In addition to viewing the metrics in the UI, they are also available as JSON. This gives developers an easy way to create new visualizations and monitoring tools for Spark. The JSON is available for both running applications, and in the history server. The endpoints are mounted at /api/v1. Eg., for the history server, they would typically be accessible at http://:18080/api/v1, and for a running application, at http://localhost:4040/api/v1.

The endpoints lists all available URIs and which data they expose. You can have a service which queries that data during stream processing and analyses the metrics.